# Meaning of せい conjugation of する?

Tags: verbs, conjugations

I came upon this line of dialogue in a book I'm reading, from a character who has old-fashioned speech patterns:

できる限りの鶏肉を用意せい…

I assume this せい is some form of the verb する, though I'm not even sure if it's a regional dialect or some remnant of classical Japanese. I can find plenty of examples of the same usage on Google, but no actual explanation or grammar notes for it in any of my usual go-to sites and reference books.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Verb する has two imperative forms (命令形) with the same meaning: しろ and せよ.  せい is an old-fashioned sound variation of the latter form.

Comment: Thank you! Sometimes the answer stares at me right in the face, and yet it still eludes me...